# Hitting ball at the end of paddle shows random motion

Tags: python, pygame, kivy

In kivy pong tutorial there is whole code which I run on my computer and it works absolutely fine but in case of hitting the ball at the edges of paddle show crazy motion. I am not sure what's happening. I tried observing it many times and I think that ball is colliding within the paddle so many times so the speed is kept on increasing X1.1 which is turn causes random motion. But how can I make it work ? I tried changing the clock function time but then no result. There suppose to be collision check method but then I am not able to do it. Any help ?

Code (I have not attached .kv file I don't think it is required here):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock

class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)
    orientation = ObjectProperty([0, 0])

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball) :
                vx, vy = ball.velocity
                offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
                bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
                vel = bounced * 1.1
                ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        #bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        #bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        #went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))




    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could, for instance, keep track of whether the ball has left the paddle since the last collision. If it has, apply the new collision as normal. If it hasn't, don't apply any new collision until it has.